# Extract all values from list of lists with same vector name

Tags: r

I have the following list of lists:

```
list_1 <- list(a = 2, b = 3)
list_2 <- list(a=c(5,6), b= c(2,3))
list_3 <- list(a=c(10,5,8,1), b=c(9,6,2,9))
list_4 <- list(a=c(2,5,58), b=c(69,6,23))
mylist <- list(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4)
names(mylist)<- c("list_1", "list_2", "list_3", "list_4")
```

Now what I want is to extract all the a and b values from the lists and save them either as a data.frame with the corresponding list names as a ID column like:

```
    [ID]      [a]   [b]
[1] list_1    2     3
[2] list_2    5     2
[3] list_2    6     3
[4] list_3    10    9              
[5] list_3    5     6
[6] list_3    8     2
[7] list_3    1     9    
[8] list_4    2     69
[9] list_4    5     6
[10] list_4   58    23
```

or as variables, such that `a` contains all a values, `b` contains all b values, and `ID` contains the corresponding list IDs:

```
[a]
2 5 6 10 5 8 1 2 5 58
[b]
3 2 3 9 6 2 9 69 6 23
[ID]
"list_1" "list_2" "list_2" "list_3" "list_3" "list_3" "list_3" "list_4" "list_4" "list_4"
```

I tried the second approach with a for loop but couldn't mange to archive the desired result. But even if I could manage that I don't know how I would solve the ID thing. It would be great if the solution could be a general one, because I have many such lists of different lengths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, you could loop through the names of `mylist`, for each name generating a data frame with that name as the `ID` variable and all variables from the relevant element of `mylist`. Then you could combine all the generated data frames together with `do.call` and `rbind`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(names(mylist), function(x) data.frame(c(ID=x, mylist[[x]]))))
#        ID  a  b
# 1  list_1  2  3
# 2  list_2  5  2
# 3  list_2  6  3
# 4  list_3 10  9
# 5  list_3  5  6
# 6  list_3  8  2
# 7  list_3  1  9
# 8  list_4  2 69
# 9  list_4  5  6
# 10 list_4 58 23
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just `rbind` the lists and add the row names as `ID`. This way you don't need to worry about the column names at all. Or you can just leave the `row.names` as the `ID` and just settle with `do.call(rbind.data.frame, mylist)`

```
res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, mylist)
res$ID <- sub("\\..*", "", row.names(res))
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#     a  b     ID
# 1   2  3 list_1
# 2   5  2 list_2
# 3   6  3 list_2
# 4  10  9 list_3
# 5   5  6 list_3
# 6   8  2 list_3
# 7   1  9 list_3
# 8   2 69 list_4
# 9   5  6 list_4
# 10 58 23 list_4
```

---

Alternately you could also do

```
res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, mylist)
as.list(cbind(res, ID = row.names(res)))
# $a
# [1]  2  5  6 10  5  8  1  2  5 58
# 
# $b
# [1]  3  2  3  9  6  2  9 69  6 23
# 
# $ID
# [1] list_1    list_2.2  list_2.3  list_3.4  list_3.5  list_3.6  list_3.7  list_4.8  list_4.9  list_4.10
# Levels: list_1 list_2.2 list_2.3 list_3.4 list_3.5 list_3.6 list_3.7 list_4.10 list_4.8 list_4.9
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of extra. I think the `purrr` package offers something pretty good in this case. The following returns a list that is similar to one by David Arenburg. The difference is that the ID part stays as names in each vector.

```
library(purrr)
mylist %>% zip_n(.simplify = TRUE)

#$a
# list_1 list_21 list_22 list_31 list_32 list_33 list_34 list_41 
#      2       5       6      10       5       8       1       2 
#list_42 list_43 
#      5      58 
#
#$b
# list_1 list_21 list_22 list_31 list_32 list_33 list_34 list_41 
#      3       2       3       9       6       2       9      69 
#list_42 list_43 
#      6      23
```